# What is the Guava equivalent to StringUtils.removeEnd?

Tags: guava, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang

I struggle to find a Guava equivalent for commons-lang [StringUtils.removeEnd](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#removeEnd%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Is there such a method or do I have to use a Joiner and a Splitter in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Guava provides such a method, but it's a trivial one-liner:

```
s = s.endsWith(suffix) ? s.substring(0, s.length() - suffix.length()) : s;
```

Comment: StringUtils handles null inputs as well, so it might be a little more complicated. Besides, using the util method "removeEnd" increases readability.

Comment: Guava, in general, doesn't try to be null-safe. Your code should take care of that. Nothing forbids you to put that one-liner into a method. Guava doesn't provide it, probably because it's an uncommon use-case that is trivial to implement with standard String methods.